# assigning value to row.names of ffdf

Tags: r, ff

I have a ff dataframe variable whose name is created within the code, at each iteration of the loop. I want to set the rownames of this variable to NULL, however the below code doesn't work. Could somebody please suggest a solution?

```
a="foo"
row.names(eval(parse(text=paste(a, "_USD.ff", sep="")))) <- NULL
```

Comment: `rownames(ffobject) <- NULL` works for me.

Comment: ffobject in your example is a string? because it doesnt work for me.

Comment: It's not a matter of string rather than the object should be something that has 2+ dimensions. If it's a matrix, it will work. Vectors, as a rule, don't have rownames.

Comment: I think you havent understood the nature of the problem: so foo_USD.ff is a ffdf object (2+ dimensions). However, I want to reference this object inside the row.names by its string name, "foo_USD.ff". See below answer which works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a solution to my problem:

```
a="foo"
eval(parse(text=paste("row.names(", a, "_ATMF_USD.ff)<-NULL", sep="")))
```

this works.